# Get Confusion Matrix From a Keras Multiclass Model

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am building a multiclass model with Keras.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint], validation_data=(X_test, y_test))  # starts training
```

Here is how my test data looks like (it's text data).

```
X_test
Out[25]: 
array([[621, 139, 549, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [621, 139, 543, ...,   0,   0,   0]])

y_test
Out[26]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

After generating predictions...

```
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
predictions
Out[27]: 
array([[ 0.29071924,  0.2483743 ,  0.46090645],
       [ 0.29566404,  0.45295066,  0.25138539]], dtype=float32)
```

I did the following to get the confusion matrix.

```
y_pred = (predictions > 0.5)

confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-430e012b2078>", line 1, in <module>
    confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 252, in confusion_matrix
    raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)

ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported
```

However, I am getting the above error.

How can I get a confusion matrix when doing a multiclass neural network in Keras?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Your input to `confusion_matrix` must be an array of int not one hot encodings.

```
matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1))
```

Comment: In case it's too subtle, this answer clarifies that the question was asked about `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix()`, not `tensorflow.math.confusion_matrix()`, which might be expected given the tag `keras`

Comment: How can I use it for the image dataset?

Comment: @JakeStevens-Haas Thx: that is actually a material flaw in the answer: this answer should be rewritten