# How to get confusion matrix of a CNN model

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix, conv-neural-network

I have used CNN model for binary image classification. I am able to get accuracy and loss but don't know how to get confusion matrix of such model. Also how graph can be plotted of accuracy and loss?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
import numpy as np

X = np.array(pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb")))
Y = np.array(pickle.load(open("Y.pickle","rb")))

#scaling our image data
X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()
#model.add(Conv2D(64 ,(3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(64 ,(3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(2048))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
             optimizer = "adam",
             metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs = 15, validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get confusion matrix from a Keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56458526/get-confusion-matrix-from-a-keras-model)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to plot loss and accuracy when training a model with Tensorflow and Keras is using Tensorboard (https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started)

Tensorflow also provides a function to compute the confusion matrix : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/confusion_matrix